# Traefik 2/Docker using www returns 404

Tags: docker, traefik

I'm quite new to Traefik and I have currently got it half working, but I am a little stuck.

I am using Traefik and docker. I would like to point my domain to a Wordpress instance. The current setup I have below redirects traffic from http.domain.com and https.domain.com to the WordPress instance, but when I try [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) it hits a 404. My current setup is below, what is it that I'm misunderstanding?

[image: My current setuo]

I'm using Portainer to manage my docker containers and labels as Traefik commands. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this in your `rule` definitions:

```
"traefik.http.routers.blog.rule=Host(`example.com`) || Host(`www.example.org`)"
```

You can also use `HostRegexp`, see here: https://docs.traefik.io/routing/routers/#rule